# Using WatchService to identify changes in .txt

Tags: java, text, watchservice

I am attempting to scan through a directory for any changes to multiple files using the WatchService.  I am able to identify the exact text file in the given directory that has been changed.  I am wondering if there is some way to have my program then show exactly what the change was, to then search that change for specific variables?

A new entry would look something like this

07/02/15 11:44, 88, 55

I would want to pull this line, then scan whether the 88 or 55 goes to 100 or higher.

This is my current code.

```
public void scanChanges() {
    Path p = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\achamberlain\\Desktop\\Data");
    try {
        WatchService watcher = p.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
        p.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY);

        for (;;) {
            WatchKey key = null;
            key= watcher.take();

            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                String location;
                location = (p + "\\" + event.context().toString());
                Watcher sendlocation = new Watcher();
                sendlocation.readFile(location);
                key.reset();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    }
}

public class Watcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Modify modClass = new Modify();
        modClass.scanChanges();   
    }

    //changes "location" to "fileName" for use in this class
    public void readFile(String fileName){
        System.out.println(fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I am seeing what the file that is changed, but not what changed about the file.